# Do rare-color weapons have special features in Dying Light?

Tags: dying-light

I'm about 80% through the main quest, and just picked up a purple Desert Police Rifle.  The attributes say it has 184 damage, 75 accuracy and 100 rate of fire.  Somewhere along the way, I picked up a blue Advanced Police Rifle that has twice the damage at 368, with the other attributes being identical (other than price).

I also have Tahir's Weapon (a machete), that's orange and has 245 damage, and I've got some other blue machetes with more than three times that damage.

I'm wondering if the rare color (purple and orange) weapons have any special hidden features that make them worth keeping, as compared to the more available colors of weapons?  The Borderlands games do that, so I was wondering if Dying Light has similar meanings to the rare weapons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Item rarity will only affect the **stats** of your weapons. This means handling, durabilty and damage will be increased compared to a weapon of lower quality.

Keep in mind that every weapon also has a hidden **level**. This is why an orange quality item from earlier in the game will almost always be worse than a blue item from near the end of the game.

The only way to get special effects on your weapons (fire/bleed/toxic for example) is by crafting weapon upgrades.